# STM32f2xx could not work with maximum frequency

Tags: frequency, clock, stm32, flash, error

I'm using default configuration (according to UM1061, RCC section) to configure an SMT32F215RG to work with 120MHZ CPU clock.
here is my configurations:

```
/* PLL_VCO = (HSE_VALUE or HSI_VALUE / PLL_M) * PLL_N */
#define PLL_M 25 /* For HSE value equal to 25 MHz */
#define PLL_N 240
/* SYSCLK = PLL_VCO / PLL_P */
#define PLL_P 2
/* USB OTG FS, SDIO and RNG Clock = PLL_VCO / PLLQ */
#define PLL_Q 5
/* In this example:
PLL_VCO = 240 MHz
SYSCLK = 120 MHz
*/
/***************************************************************/
/* PLL (clocked by HSE) used as System clock(SYSCLK) source */
/***************************************************************/
__IO uint32_t StartUpCounter = 0, HSEStartUpStatus = 0;
/* Enable HSE */
RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
/* Wait till HSE is ready */
HSEStartUpStatus = RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp();
if (HSEStartUpStatus == SUCCESS)
{
/* Flash 3 wait state, prefetch buffer and cache ON */
FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_3);
FLASH_PrefetchBufferCmd(ENABLE);
FLASH_InstructionCacheCmd(ENABLE);
FLASH_DataCacheCmd(ENABLE);
/* HCLK = SYSCLK */
RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1);
/* PCLK2 = HCLK/2 */
RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);
/* PCLK1 = HCLK/4 */
RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div4);
/* Configure the main PLL clock to 120 MHz */
RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSE, PLL_M, PLL_N, PLL_P, PLL_Q);
/* Enable the main PLL */
RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
/* Wait till the main PLL is ready */
while (RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY) == RESET)
{}
/* Select the main PLL as system clock source */
RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);

/* Wait till the main PLL is used as system clock source */
while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL)
{}
}
else
{ /* If HSE fails to start-up, user can add here some code
to deal with this error */
}
```

for testing that, I'm using a blinking LED (in pooling mode), VDD is 3.3 volts & I use a 25 MHZ quartz.
The problem is here that the program does NOT work at all or it begins to work & stops after one or two seconds.
I used a debugger to trace it & I found that a Hard Fault occures & execution enters into HardFault_Handler infinity loop of startup_stm32fxx.s
I checked the board several times & I'm sure it has no issue, also the same program works fine when I decrease cpu clock to a lower value (by changing PLL params, e.g set PLL_P=4).
Seems all frequencies above 100MHZ causes some kind of problem. I guessed it may related to Flash access latency, but according to the datasheet with 3.3V of VDD it must works with 3 wait states & changing wait cycles did not helped me.

Comment: What's the value of the [HFSR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Cihdjcfc.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to put capacitors on VCAP pins & it causes the issue. Connecting a 2.2UF capacitor on one of the VCAP pins solved the problem

Comment: Vcap is decouping cpacitor for mcu internal voltage, which is 1.2v, failed to connect them will result bad power delivery network.